# Is the relative clause used correctly here?

Tags: relative-clauses, that

> Get a first-hand feel for the Nomad life with the knowledge that this 
>   team has a wealth of experience in dealing with international visitors.

Is the part *that this team has a wealth of experience* correct here? I think it should have been "*Get a first-hand feel for the Nomad life with the knowledge that this team has in dealing with international visitors.*

After a relative clause "that", an independent sentence should come; however, the independent sentence "*this team has a wealth of experience in dealing with international visitors."* sounds wrong. Why is that? How could you correct it without losing the idea that the team has a wealth of experience?

Comment: This is a very confused sentence.

Comment: It makes me confused too.